# BitmapFactory decodeStream is not working in listview

Tags: java, android

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> web;
    private final ArrayList<InputStream> imglist;

    public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> alist,
            ArrayList<InputStream> bitmapArray) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_custom, alist);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = alist;
        this.imglist = bitmapArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_custom, null);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.drawer_item_text);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.drawer_item_icon);

        txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));

        if (imglist.get(position) != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imglist
                    .get(position)));
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        System.out.println("Image Input sream " + imglist.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
bitmapArray.add(openPhoto(contact_id_long));

CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, Alist,
                        bitmapArray); 

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            contactId);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
            Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { Contacts.Photo.PHOTO }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (data != null) {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Custom arrayadapter, I can able to see the text but not images but when i check in log The InputStream is working fine, if i use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` outside the list view i can able to see the images. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store a list of `InputStream` objects and decode bitmaps from them. But an input stream will return `null` after once used. Store paths instead of input streams.
Also there is such thing as marking and then resetting an input stream (`mark()` and `reset()` methods of `InputStream` class). But I don't recommend to use them. As I remember there was a bug concerning this methods using and bitmaps decoding.

Comment: I don't have paths, can u explain me a bit more, i have update my code please have a look.

Comment: `InputStream` reading (decoding) is performed only in one direction. Some implementations of `InputStream` support marking an input stream and then returning back to the mark (resetting), but some implementations don't support it and you can't read the stream again. But I see you get your bitmaps from device, not from network, so you can get a path of an image.

Comment: Another method: you can store `Uri photoUri`. And get `InputStream` in `getView` with this method: `InputStream openContactPhotoInputStream (ContentResolver cr, Uri contactUri)` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream(android.content.ContentResolver, android.net.Uri)) . And decode the stream with `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` as you do now.